# CakePHP 3 - Unable to manually login user

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am able to login the user if the user enters their credentials on a login form. I am unable to login the user if I try to manually log them in. Really strange.

Code for login using form [this works just fine]:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect('/cars');
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

Code for manual login [this doesnt work]:

```
public function loginManually()
    {
        try {
            $user = $this->Users->find()
            ->where(['username' => 'abc@xyz.com'])
            ->contain(['Profiles'])
            ->firstOrFail();
            $this->Auth->setUser($user->toArray());
            return $this->redirect('/cars');
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            Log::write('error', $ex);
            $this->Flash->error(__('An error occurred Please try again'));
        }
        return $this->redirect('/login');
    }
```

Upon debugging - the code works fine up to `$this-Auth->setUser($user->toArray());` - but when I redirect it to `/cars` the system returns an error stating the user is not logged in. I am baffled - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

instead of email get user record by primary key (id) .
this is work for me

```
$user = $this->Modelname->get($id);
$this->Auth->setUser($user->toArray());
debug($this->Auth->user());
```